# VBA sorting run time error 438

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, syntax

I'm using a VBA macro in Access to put data into Excel. So far things are going well, but now that I have data in Excel I want to sort the data based on this new column I made. I've searched around for different sort syntax examples, but nothing is working. The closest is this one which gives me a run time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method". All I want to do is sort the data from the entire sheet based on the first column's data (just numbers).

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
.Visible = True
.Workbooks.Add
.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End With

'More code is here in between that gets data into Excel file
'This code not shown works as expected 

With xlApp
.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
.Cells(1, 1).Value = "DayOfWeek"
For i = 2 To 10000
    .Cells(i, 1).Value = Weekday(xlApp.Cells(i, 2).Value, vbMonday)
Next i
'Works as expected up to here, next line is problem
.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending
End With
```

EDIT: Added in the part where I initialize the xlApp, as well as fixed the Order1 and added Value to Cells calls to make the code more clear as suggested. Also, it should be noted that in debugging I can see that everything up to the sort call is giving the correct output in an Excel workbook.

Comment: could you trace your procedure using F8 key and tell at which line the error occurs?

Comment: It occurs at the .Sort line. Sorry I tried to comment it as the problem line

Comment: Sort() isn't a method of the Excel Application object.  Maybe try `.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order:=xlAscending`

Comment: Trying that I got a run time error 1004 " Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: Can you show more of your code? in particular how is `xlApp` declared and assigned?

Answer (score 0):

```
    With xlApp
        .Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "DayOfWeek"
        For i = 2 To 10000
            .Cells(i, 1) = Weekday(.Cells(i, 2), vbMonday)
        Next i
        'Works as expected up to here, next line is problem
        .Cells.Sort Header:=xlYes, Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending
    End With
```

Comment: Tried this, but got a run time error 1004, "sort method of range class failed"

Comment: Can you try the above one more time?

Comment: If I try to put it in a separate sub then it will have trouble finding the Excel workbook I make earlier. I tried anyways though, and it's giving me a run time error 424 "Object required" on the third line (.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Put the above code in where you were using it before and remove the separate sub you created.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of issues here:-

1. I suspect xlApp is the `Application` object, where you are trying to run operations against a `Worksheet` object.  Replace `xlApp` with either another variable declared and assigned to a `Worksheet` or simply use `Activesheet`.
2. As good practice, you should always refer to the `.Value` property of the `Cell` object, rather than relying on the default property.  This makes reading and maintenance much easier.
3. The `Sort` method does not operate on the `Worksheet` level, but on the `Range` object.
4. The parameter `Order` does not exist. It is `Order1`, which complements `Key1`.
5. From what I can gather, you have headings in row 1. You need to amend your `Sort` statement to skip sorting the headers.

Here is the final code block:

```
With xlApp.ActiveSheet
  .Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
  .Cells(1, 1).Value = "DayOfWeek"
  For i = 2 To 10000
    .Cells(i, 1).Value = Weekday(.Cells(i, 2).Value, vbMonday)
  Next i
  'Works as expected up to here, next line is problem
  .Range("A1").Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: These tid bits were very helpful, but the code unfortunately still doesn't work. When I run this code I get a 1004 error because the first few lines need to have a reference to the xlApp. Even if I take out just the last line and put it in its own With Active Sheet block, I still get a 424 "object required" error. If I put it in a With xlApp.ActiveSheet block instead I get a 1004 "sort method of range class failed" error. I don't know what's still wrong with the syntax.

Comment: The code I gave you works 100% for me - I tested it. Is there more code in this block that you have omitted for posting? If so, please put it up so I can get the big picture. The code you posted shows no dependency on anything other than a `Worksheet` object.

Comment: It just clicked that are you running running this from outside Excel. If you are outside Excel, then you need to prefix `Activesheet` with `xlApp`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the range before you sort it:

```
Dim RngRange As Range
Set RngRange = Sheet.Range("A1:A999")
RngRange.Select
RngRange.Sort Key1:=RngRange, Order1:=xlAscending
```

If you want to sort one column and include another in the result, the RngRange is all the columns you want to sort, the key is what column to sort

Most of the examples online are actually wrong, drive me crazy.